# In Emacs org-mode, Latex export of literal string containing "\__" giving problem

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I am trying to export a literal string from Emacs Org-mode to Latex for subsequent export to PDF. The literal string is:

`str1\__str2`

I have tried the following input in the Org file:

```
\verb+str1\__str2+
```

This produces the following code in the .tex file:

```
\verb+str1\hspace{3ex}str2+
```

I expected the following code in the .tex file:

```
\verb+str1\__str2+
```

I have also tried the following in the Org file:

```
\begin{verbatim}
str1\__str2
\end{verbatim}
```

This produces the following code in .tex file:

```
\begin{verbatim}
str1\hspace{3ex}str2
\end{verbatim}
```

Including the following option in the Org file has no effect on the output:

```
#+OPTIONS:     ^:{}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the verbatim block, which you indicated above you're ok with, then this:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
   str1\__str2
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Produces this:

```
\begin{verbatim}
str1\__str2
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Thanks, Wes, for your response. I need to insert this literal string in an Emacs Org table. I can only include a single line per cell in this table. So, this verbatim block will not work for my case. --Sharad

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but you didn't specify that constraint.

Comment: I suspect this is actually a bug in the latex exporting and should probably be reported as a bug to the org-mode developers.  You shouldn't *need* to do anything special in the first place.

Comment: Indeed.  Sharad, please report this as a bug.  M-x org-submit-bug-report RET

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org-entities-user` to create your own entities with different translations on export.

Setting it to e.g. `(("textbackslash" "\\textbackslash" nil "\\" "\\" "\\" "\\"))` will translate `\textbackslash` to `\textbackslash` on LaTeX output and to `\` for all other outputs.

Answer (score 1):

This ugly workaround may help:

```
| str1\textbackslash{}\_\_str2  |
```

I cannot get the backslash thing out of the way, which will not look good on HTML export.